# .NET C# Method with Iset<> input called from Python 2.7

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7

So I have a method in .NET C# that is supposed to be called like this:

```
public void PropagateToViews(
    View view,
    ISet<ElementId> parallelViews
    )
```

It looks relatively straight forward with the exception of the `ISet` that I cannot figure out how to create in Python 2.7 (Iron Python).

I tried importing `System.Collections.Generic` and from it a variety of different things like  `HashSet, IList, ISet, SortedSet etc`  but each presents an error.

Trying to instantiate the  `ISetElementId`  tells me that it can't be done due to abstract class properties.

When I try feeding  `ListElementId` that tells me that it was expecting ISet.

SortedSet also returns an error saying that it couldn't compare elements.

Can someone educate me on how to call that method from Python? I specifically would like to understand ISet class implementation in Python environment.

Thank you,

Comment: What version of .NET are you running?  What error does it give when you try to import System.Collections.Generic?  It should allow "from System.Collections.Generic import ISet" and then something=ISet[ElementId]() to create.

Comment: @MattJordan import works fine, but ISet[ElementId]() cannot be instantiated as that is an abstract class. The exact error is: Cannot create instances of ISet[ElementId] because it is abstract

Comment: I am using .NET 4.0 and IronPython 2.7

Comment: Using HashSet should work. Have you tried HashSet and if this does not work, what problem do you get?

Comment: when i tried HashSet it threw this at me: AttributeError: attribute 'HashSet' of 'namespace#' object is read-only

Comment: Have you simply try to send a python set Set()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following successfully:

I have a C# sample project to be called:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class ElementId
    {
        public string Name{set;get;}
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public static void TestMethod(ISet<ElementId> fSet)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Number of Elements  in Set: " + fSet.Count.ToString());

            foreach(var lElement in fSet)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(lElement.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is compiled as ClassLibrary1.dll and installed into the global assembly cache.

Then I have the following Python script:

```
import clr
import System

# Load System.Core assembly that contains HashSet
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
from System.Collections.Generic import HashSet

# Load Sample Assembly
clr.AddReference("ClassLibrary1")
from ClassLibrary1 import ElementId
from ClassLibrary1 import TestClass

# Create HashSet
myHashSet = HashSet[ElementId]()

# Fill HashSet with two objects 
item = ElementId()
item.Name = "Hello"
myHashSet.Add(item)

item2 = ElementId()
item2.Name = "World"
myHashSet.Add(item2)

# Now call test method and pass the Set
TestClass.TestMethod(myHashSet)
```

The script runs without error in the Iron Python console and as expected I get three message boxes, saying "Number of Elements in Set: 2", "Hello" and "World"

In order to use a type in .NET, you need to do two things:

1. You need to load the Assembly (DLL) that the type is declared in. In Python you do that via `clr.AddReference()`.
2. You need to import the namespace in which the type is declared. In Python, you do that via `import`.

In the documentation you can see that the class `HashSet` is in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` and in the assembly `System.Core.dll`. So in order to use the type HashSet you need both:

```
clr.AddReference("System.Core")
from System.Collections.Generic import HashSet
```

Some of the more basic types are in the assemblies `System.dll` and `mscorlib.dll` which are always automatically loaded by the runtime.

What assembly and what namespace a type is declared in is often related. Often the name of the assembly is the beginning of the name of the namespace, but not always. Two types that are in the same namespace can actually be contained in two different assemblies. For example, most of the other types in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic` (like for example `List` or `SortedSet`) are not part of `System.Core.dll` but part of `System.dll` so that you can use them without any explicit assembly referencing.

Comment: I did try HashSet, but now that I tried it again, it actually worked. I am not sure what I was doing wrong, since I was doing pretty much the same thing. Does, <code> clr.AddReference("System.Core") </code> makes any difference when importing a module/assembly? That's the only difference between what I was trying. Thanks!

Comment: @konrad Yes, that makes all the difference. I added some information on clr.AddReference to the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I see now, why this was an issue. Great job.